# Avery Weigh-Tronix Web server saving user data

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am currently developing a web application for an Avery Weigh-Tronix truck scale. the computer that receives the weight data has a web server on it. The web server by default has a page that reads the data the scale is out putting. You can go to www.gloryfeed.com to see what im talking about. The server seems to be a type of a black box you cannot install any additional back end server libraries or software there is no command line. So using PHP scripts, AJAX, node.js and mySQL is out of the question. So i am currently stuck using HTML, CSS, and JS to try to complete this task. If anyone has any ideas on how to save user entered data on the html page back to the server that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Host a PHP/etc. script on another server that uses curl to fetch and parse out the value from the scale's webserver.

Comment: So host a completely different website that just pulls the weight from the existing website?

Comment: Sure, if you can't do anything to the main server.

Comment: What does that normally look like? Sorry im new to this. Is there documentation you can point me to?

Comment: http://php.net/curl